# How do I configure the Azure Devops account for a Data factory instead of Git?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

```
 "repoConfiguration": {
                                "type": "FactoryGitHubConfiguration",
                                "accountName": "[parameters('gitAccountName')]",
                                "repositoryName": "[parameters('gitRepositoryName')]",
                                "collaborationBranch": "[parameters('gitBranchName')]",
                                "rootFolder": "[parameters('gitRootFolder')]"
                            }
```

I have added the above lines in template under the properties for configuring Git. Let me know how do we do it for Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this template ...

```
        "repoConfiguration": {
        "type": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration",
        "accountName": "parameter_value",
        "repositoryName": "parameter_value",
        "projectName": "parameter_value",
        "collaborationBranch": "parameter_value",
        "rootFolder": "parameter_value",
        "tenantId": "parameter_value"
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the encryption part of the ARM Template to enable CUSTOMER MANAGED KEYS @Raunak Jhawar

Comment: yes does that have an impact on this ? @Raunak Jhawar

Comment: You should post a new question so that responses on SO don't get mixed up.

Comment: What question ?

Comment: @ Raunak Jhawar what is the new question ?